# odoo, its posible to create a kanban widget like a form widget?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view

as the question title say, is posible to create widgets for a kanban view? 
like in forms, extending from others widgets? 
Is there any tutorial or source code to take a look? because the odoo documentation is very poor and I can´t find anythig like that

Comment: Check out the Odoo Community Association's page https://odoo-community.org/ and github repo https://github.com/OCA?. There may be something there. I see no reason you cant create widgets specific for a kanban. Actually, just thought of one one2many for kanban. https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/8.0/web_one2many_kanban/

Comment: Hi @PhillipStack thanks for all your help on my questions, I will take a look on that places tath you give me.  I put my questions Here because i can´t doit in the odoo comunity forum, because I don´t have enough karma to do it, and I don´t know how to increasse mi karma. but again thanks for all